# the 2nd step can not fetch data inserted by 1st step

Tags: spring, spring-batch, jdbctemplate

I configure 2 steps in my job. 
The first job is to read from a csv file and writer it to db
below it he code of writer

```
public class TempTableWriter implements ItemWriter<Module> {

@Autowired
DataSource ds;

@Autowired
ModuleService moduleService;

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Module> items) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    
    moduleService.updateModuleList(items);
    
}
```

}

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ModuleService {
@Autowired
ModuleDao moduleDao;


@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED)
public List<Module> getModuleList() {
    return moduleDao.getModuleList();
}

public void updateModuleList(List<? extends Module> items) {
    items.forEach(item -> {
        
        moduleDao.updateModuleList(p1, p2, p3, p4);
    });
    
}
```

}

```
@Repository
public class ModuleDao {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("moduleMapper")
private RowMapper moduleMapper;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbctemplate;

public List<Module> getModuleList() {
    
    return jdbctemplate.query("select * from[schema].[t1] ORDER BY p1",
            moduleMapper);
}


public void updateModuleList(String requestId, String fileName,
        String orcStatus,String context) {
    jdbctemplate.update("insert into [schema].[t1]　values(?,?,?,?)", p1, p2,
            p3,p4);
            
}
```

}

then on the 2nd step when I try the fetch the data which I stored by step1, it always get null, but after the job completing,I could find them really stored in db.
Similarly I tried to use JdbcItemWriter to save the records but I still can not fetch them by the next step.

Comment: You seem to have an issue with your transactions configuration. If step 1 is correctly configured, step 2 should see any db updates done in step 1. You are using `@Transactional` on the service used in `TempTableWriter`. This writer is called within a transaction driven by spring batch already, so this might be the cause of your issue. If you provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the reproduces the issue, I can try to help.

Comment: thanks for the replay sincerely.I have solved this problem...I also think its a transaction issue at the begining and finally I find I just load the db data when I  define the reader of the step2..so before the step1 finishs the load method will be invoked. Instead I wanna to load the data in the Step listener after step one, but the @Autowired does not affect if I define it in the StepListener, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: No, sorry. But good to hear you solved your issue.